# How does HttpServletRequest.getParameter work?

Tags: java, servlets

I have a code in search.java which uses getParameter and xmltransform.
I am using search.java to search a database of books depending on the title given. For all the criteria I get the output. But when I give C++ as the title in index.jsp which sends the value of the title to search.java. The search.java uses getParameter method to receive the input. My program gives me the output but taking C as the title.

The problem is that the getParameter is called twice. First when it is called it gets C++ but after xmltransform when I use getParameter again it gets C. That is why I get only books pertaining to the title C.

The code is as follows

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Boolean access = (Boolean) request.getSession().getAttribute("access");
    if (access == null)
        access = false;

    if (contextPath == null)
        //contextPath = HOST + getServletContext().getContextPath() + "\\";
        //changed the above line to get http://localhost:8085/SemanticWeb
        contextPath = HOST + getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/";
        System.out.println(contextPath);
    System.out.println("Search in doget");
    SemanticSearch semsearch = new SemanticSearch(request.getSession());

    System.out.println("After getsession");
    semsearch.loadData(REALPATH + RDFDATASOURCEFILE);
    String xml = request.getParameter("xml");
    String title = request.getParameter("s");

    /*Writer writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.write(request.getParameter("s"));*/

    System.out.println("the value of s taken by getparameter " +title);



    System.out.println("After ASOURCEFILE");
    // Ask just for XML Response
    if (xml != null && xml.equals("1") && title != null) {
        System.out.println("this is xml "+xml);
        //response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");
        System.out.println("Search for Title in search.java");
        System.out.println("This is the title "+title);
        semsearch.searchForTitleXML(response.getOutputStream(), null, title);
        System.out.println("Back in Search.java");
        return;
    }

System.out.println("This is the title just before xmltransform "+title);
    xmlTransform(contextPath + "Search?xml=1&s=" + title, contextPath
            + (access ? "xsl\\data_admin.xsl" : "xsl\\data.xsl"), response.getOutputStream());
    //System.out.println(xmlResponse);
    System.out.println("Done in Search.java");
}
public static void xmlTransform(String xml_uri, String xsl_uri,
        OutputStream out) {
    // JAXP reads Data trough Source-Interface
    Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(xml_uri);
    Source xsltSource = new StreamSource(xsl_uri);
            System.out.println("I am here");
              System.out.println("This is the xmlsource "+xml_uri);
            System.out.println("This is the xmlsource "+xsl_uri);

    // Factory-Pattern supports different XSLT-Processors
    TransformerFactory transFact = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    System.out.println("checking");
    Transformer trans;
    System.out.println("checking_1");
    try {
        System.out.println("checking_1");
        trans = transFact.newTransformer(xsltSource);
        System.out.println("checking_2");
        trans.transform(xmlSource, new StreamResult(out));
        System.out.println("checking_3");
        System.out.println("Done here");
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
        //System.out.println("After error in xmltransfrom");
        System.out.println("Caught here");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        System.out.println("Here I am there");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


}
```

The output is as follows

```
http://localhost:8086/SemanticWeb/
Search in doget
After getsession
the value of s taken by getparameter C++
After ASOURCEFILE
This is the title just before xmltransform C++
I am here
This is the xmlsource http://localhost:8086/SemanticWeb/Search?xml=1&s=C++
This is the xmlsource http://localhost:8086/SemanticWeb/xsl\data.xsl
checking
checking_1
checking_1
checking_2
http://localhost:8086/SemanticWeb/
Search in doget
After getsession
the value of s taken by getparameter C  
After ASOURCEFILE
this is xml 1
Search for Title in search.java
This is the title C  
Search for title in semantic search.java
PREFIX kb: 
SELECT * WHERE {?x kb:Price ?price. ?x kb:Currency ?currency. ?x kb:Title ?title. ?x kb:Count ?count. OPTIONAL {?x kb:Description ?description}.FILTER regex(?title, "(^|\\W)C  (\\W|$)")}ORDER BY ?title
The above query is due to semanticsearch.java file.
Done in SemanticSearch
Back in Search.java
checking_3
Done here.
```

Can you tell me why getParameter when called twice erases ++ from C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` is a special character in URLs which represents a space. It look like that you're manually setting the parameter instead of letting the browser set it, like so:

```
<a href="Search?xml=1&s=C++">Search C++</a>
```

This way it will end up as a `C` with two spaces thereafter. You need to [URL-encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the parameter. The URL-encoded value of `+` is `%21`.

```
<a href="Search?xml=1&s=C%21%21">Search C++</a>
```

If you want to do this programmatically, use either [`URLEncoder#encode()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) in Java (Servlet/EL) side or the [`<c:url>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/url.html) in JSP side.

Comment: The variable s is filled in index.jsp which is encoded in index.jsp using encodeURIComponent(s) and this is passed to Search.java file above. Here we use getParameter() and obtain the value C++ which is shown in the output file. The same search.java file also runs xmlTransform which again calls getParameter() and gets the value as C  .Why does this happen? What do I do to change this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Can you please try with quote in parameter value

http://localhost:8086/SemanticWeb/Search?xml='1'&s='C++'

Comment: Do you want I need to add the quote in the following line xmlTransform(contextPath + "Search?xml=1&s=" + title, contextPath
            + (access ? "xsl\\data_admin.xsl" : "xsl\\data.xsl"), response.getOutputStream());

Comment: xmlTransform(contextPath + "Search?xml='1'&s='" + title +"'", contextPath
            + (access ? "xsl\\data_admin.xsl" : "xsl\\data.xsl"), response.getOutputStream());

Comment: I have changed the line by adding the quote as above. But it goes to an infinite loop.

Comment: I did not get the answer and accidently instead of scrolling up I might have clicked the down vote. SOrry for that.